# Use video from web using OpenCv Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, video-capture

I'm trying to use opencv to work on the video from web (by the link). In Windows It's running fine. But in Ubuntu with python 3.6 & opencv-contrib-python (latest 3.4.3) is not working(isOpened() -> False). I installed it by pip in an anaconda environment. I can use downloaded video to computer, but I can't use It only by passing link.

Sample code:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4')
if not vcap.isOpened():
    print("File Cannot be Opened")
while(vcap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

Is it connected to default compilation? Or any other ideas?

Build intormation:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.3 
  Version control:               3.4.3

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /io/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     3.4.3

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-09-09T13:49:56Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.9.0
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (9 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ Compiler:                /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib   
    Linker flags (Debug):        -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib   
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          /opt/Qt4.8.7/lib/libQtGui.so /opt/Qt4.8.7/lib/libQtTest.so /opt/Qt4.8.7/lib/libQtCore.so /lib64/libz.so /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/libjpeg.a avcodec avformat avutil swscale dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    js world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 4.8.7 EDITION = OpenSource)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.3)
    JPEG:                        /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/libjpeg.a (ver 62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.34)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.21.104)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 58.17.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 56.18.102)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 5.2.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev.h linux/videodev2.h

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python (ver 3.6.5)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.6m.a (ver 3.6.5)
    numpy:                       /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.3)
    packages path:               lib/python3.6/site-packages

  Python (for build):            /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        NO

  Install to:                    /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```